# Parsing JSON to Excel - Data Extraction

Tags: json, excel, vba

My code below was working fine, but for some reason I am getting a "Not Found" results in Excel. If I copy the URL and put any stock symbol for example AAPL, it works, but from VBA I am not getting results.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetClosePrices()
    Dim lastRow As Long, url As String, ws As Worksheet, tickers(), dateString As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Historical")
    With ws
        dateString = Format$(.Range("A1").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If lastRow >= 2 Then
           .Range("K3:K" & lastRow).ClearContents
            tickers = Application.Transpose(.Range("A3:A" & lastRow).Value)
        Else
           Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    Dim s As String, re As Object, p As String, r As String, prices(), i As Long
    ReDim prices(1 To UBound(tickers))

    p = """DATE_HERE"",""open"":[0-9.]+,""close"":(.*?),"   'Format must be YYYY-MM-DD
    p = Replace$(p, "DATE_HERE", dateString)
    url = "https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/TICKER_HERE/chart/1m?token=pk_f4e3ce4594124d8186d29dbcb40a1ac5" 'email change for new code info and gmail.
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        For i = LBound(tickers) To UBound(tickers)
            .Open "GET", Replace$(url, "TICKER_HERE", tickers(i)), False
           .SetRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
            .Send
            If .Status = 200 Then
                s = .ResponseText
                r = GetValue(re, s, p)
            Else
                r = "Failed connection"
            End If
            prices(i) = r
        Next
    End With
    ws.Cells(3, "K").Resize(UBound(prices), 1) = Application.Transpose(prices)
End Sub

Public Function GetValue(ByVal re As Object, ByVal inputString As String, ByVal pattern As String) As String
    With re
        .Global = True
        .pattern = pattern
        If .test(inputString) Then  ' returns True if the regex pattern can be matched agaist the provided string
            GetValue = .Execute(inputString)(0).submatches(0)
        Else
            GetValue = "Not found"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Please check what s causing this output.

Comment: You need to debug your code to find your issue: Go through the code step by step using F8 and analyze which steps are runing. In each step check the values of your variables.

Comment: Code works fine for me. What date are you entering in A1?

Comment: @QHarr I amsorry for the delayed response.
Code just worked again on its own. Not sure what was happening. 
Thank you for your constant support